# Git - maintain multiple versions

Tags: git

I have a git repository with a web project. I want to customize this web project for different customers.

For example i have two customers c1 and c2. So i create two git branches: c1 and c2.

Every version has the same base system but different features. If i want to add a new feature or fix a bug in one branch there is no problem. But what if i want to change something that concern both branches. This results in a large amount of merge conflicts.

Can someone show me a better solution for my problem?

Comment: If large parts are shared between the applications, you may be able to use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to store the parts that are the same.

Comment: Version control != configuration, Creating branches per customer is a slippery slope. I urge you to define what is common and what it customer specific, and have each customer have their own repo, @Powerlord 's recommendation to use submodules can help with that

Comment: Thank you Powerlord and Lars for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [GitHub](https://github.com/) feature [Fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) for solving such problems, main idea is to have separate repositories and copying commits using [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) or in some other way, with such approach both repositories will have common base and then will evolve as separate repositories.

To use same approach it is not necessary to use [GitHub](https://github.com/), you can just create several git repositories and then add additional [remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), instead of [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) you can just use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) for copy commit from one repository to another. This approach will not help with solving conflicts in some better way.

Also you should think about modular way for development of common parts as separate modules, this can be done with [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) or with some other approach related to your programming language for example in [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html) you can develop module separately and then use it from other projects using dependency management functionality of [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) or [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use now different repositories for each customer.